# Azure DevOps Rest API add existing Agent Pool to Project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I create a new project, there are **missing agent pools** which are available in collection. Indented or not, I need to add the agent pools to the new project. Therefore you have this menu:

[image]

is it possible to execute this process by **Azure DevOps Rest API**?

I seek through the documentation but all I found is [Pools - Get Agent Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). Issue here is that there is no project scope, only collection scope. So the call give me all Agent Pools from collection but not from a single project.

And even there is call to get all pools from a project, you still need a call to add a existing agent pool to the project.

How could I solve that problem?

---

```
Azure DevOps 2020.1 (on prem)
Self hosted agents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to execute this process by Azure DevOps Rest API?

Yes. You could use Rest API to add existing agent pool.

You need to check the Browser Console to get this Rest API.

[image]

**Azure DevOps 2020.1 (on prem)**

You could use the following Rest API:

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/queues?authorizePipelines=true&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "name":"xx",
    "pool":
        {
            "id":2
        }
}
```

You could get the Agent Pool id in `Organization Settings -> Agent Pools -> Target Agent Pool`.

[image]

**Update:**

To get all project agent pools, you could use the following rest api:

```
Get https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for your answer! Is there also a sneaky call the get all **agent pools** from a **project**? [Pools - Get Agent Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) only give all **agent pools** from a **collection**.

Comment: Hi @MarTin. You just need to change the method as GET , then you could get all project agent pools. Please refer to my update.

Comment: By the way, here is a doc about [Queues - Get Agent Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/get%20agent%20queues?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)  and [Queues - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). You need to make some changes about the url , then it could be used in Azure Devops Server 2020

Comment: Kevin Queues - [Get Agent Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/get%20agent%20queues?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Queues - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/queues/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) was exactly what I am looking for. These calls get covered by `azure-devops-node-api` with `getAgentQueues` and `addAgentQueue`. I only was not able to transfer that `queue` means `pool`. Now I know, it makes totally sense. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

Updated with the Version 6 API:

1. Get agent pool id from below call:

   ```
   curl -u user:pat --location --request GET 'https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName={POOL-NAME}&api-version=6.0'
   ```
2. Add existing agent pool to project:

   ```
   curl -u user:pat --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION}/{PROJECT-NAME}/_apis/distributedtask/queues?authorizePipelines=true&api-version=6.1-preview.1' --data '{"name" : "POOL-NAME", "pool" : {"id": POOL-ID}}' --header "Content-type: application/json"
   ```